# window.onresize called continuously on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I have a JS code on my page as

```
window.onresize=someFunc;
```

Now my HTML code is as below (I know frameset are OLD and should be avoided but this is something legacy code which I have);

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="abc.htm">
  <frame src="xyz.htm" noresize>
</frameset>
```

For some reasons, the window.onresize gets fired continuosly on the iPad and the method someFunc() is called.

I am not sure what might be the reason. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "continously"? Every X seconds? Every time you resize the window? Every time you click on some element?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at `someFunc` to make sure it's not doing something to trigger another resize.  I ran into something similar (legacy code with framesets) where a resize handler was changing the page size in such a way as to trigger another resize event, leading to an infinite loop where the page just got longer and longer.